.TS file missing codec information
I have a bunch of videos recorded in a .ts format. Some of the videos can be played by VLC.
However I have quite a number of files that cant be played. They show the same size as the working files, but cant be played.
Upon checking the corrupted files doenst have any codec information like codec, bitrate and such.
I tried repairing the corrupted files from renaming the extension to using Wondershare Repairit, Untruc and VLC. All doesnt seem to work.
I seek some advice from you video gurus, is there a way to rescue my corrupted files.
Thanks a lot.
